How to Statistically Test if a Community of Species at a Particular Site is Becoming More Like Another Type of Site
I have the following data frame (I'm using R here).
set.seed(2)
Site <- rep(LETTERS[1:13], length.out = 39)
Year <- rep(2019:2022, each = 13, length.out = 39)
Site_Category <- rep(c(paste("Type", rep(1:4, each = 3), sep = "_"), 
    "Test_Site"), length.out = 39)
Species_1 <- sample(1:100, 39, replace = TRUE)
Species_2 <- sample(1:25, 39, replace = TRUE)
Species_3 <- sample(1:50, 39, replace = TRUE)
Species_4 <- sample(1:500, 39, replace = TRUE)
Species_5 <- sample(1:100, 39, replace = TRUE)
My_Data <- data.frame(Site = Site, Year = Year, Site_Category = 
    Site_Category, Species_1 = Species_1, Species_2 = Species_2, 
    Species_3 = Species_3, Species_4 = Species_4, 
    Species_5 = Species_5)

Essentially what I have is four separate community data matrices (one for each year of the study). You'll also notice that I have an additional column, Site_Category, which groups certain sites together, and it also specifies that one of the sites is unique in that it's our site of interest.
Our research question is to tell if this site of interest is becoming more like one of the other site types over time.
I'm familiar with multivariate analyses like the Mantel test, the multi-response permutation procedure, and permutational analysis of variance, but I'm not just trying to see if there are differences - I want to incorporate some sort of trend analysis to tell if there is a change in a particular direction over time toward one of the other site types.
Is there some sort of statistical analysis that I can use here?

There are all kinds of solutions: they depend on what you mean by "more like" and "differences" and how you quantify those two (presently vague) concepts.  Please provide more specifics.

Thanks - can you give me some examples of what you mean? I thought we could look at the trajectory of the "Test_Site" over time to see if it tends toward one of the other site types, but this type of analysis is new to me and I'm not sure how to conceptualize it properly.

I mean that you, as the scientist, need to use your knowledge and your experimental objectives to tell us what a meaningful "difference" might be, how you wish to quantify such differences, and how you need to compare them to determine what "more like" might mean.  These are substantial questions, not purely statistical ones.

Am I right that the meaning of the species variables is "number of individuals from that species at that site", and that what you are interested in is the composition of the population at a site in terms of the species, i.e., the percentage distribution of species? Or are the absolute numbers also important for what counts as similar?

@ChristianHennig - the actual measurements we took were percent covers (I know my example here is different), but couldn't we find a robust method that handles abundances, biomasses, percent covers, presences or absences, and other types of measurements? Also, wouldn't both percents and absolute abundances give you the same answer?

@whuber - I think there may be three separate things we're interested in looking at. Let's imagine we've fit 95 % confidence interval ellipses around each group. If we had more than one plot or site of interest, then we could see if these plots or sites of interest tend toward one of the other types in location (in ordination space), ellipse size, and ellipse orientation (like which direction the major and minor axes are in). Since we only have one plot or site of interest, perhaps the only metric will be if it tends toward the centroid of any of the other groups.

@whuber - The notion of one thing tending toward another over time obviously also needs to be defined, and I'm not sure what the best option would be. Maybe there could be a parametric curve (such as a line) that would intersect with the 95 % confidence interval ellipse for one or more of the groups, or maybe the movement of these other groups over time would have to be estimated too, and a prediction could be made about where these parametric curves (one from each group) intersect with the one for the plot or site of interest.

"Also, wouldn't both percents and absolute abundances give you the same answer?" I'm with @whuber here - it's you who has to decide what you want. It's you to decide whether a situation in which percentages are the same but absolute values grossly differ should be handled as "very similar", as "very different", or as a compromise between both. It's not the numbers alone that determine the statistical method, the meaning of the numbers is important, for which you are the expert and not us.

This is the kind of situation where I think that you should probably reach out for a proper statistical collaborator rather than asking for free help on the internet. Chances are something can be done, but there may be the kind of effort required that a person who could do it wouldn't want to do for free for a stranger.

@ChristianHennig – I understand. Even if someone just gave me the names of any relevant analyses that I could read about on my own, that’d be amazing. Thank you so much.

@DavidMoore It may well not be done with reading. You may need somebody who has a deep talk with you and then custom-makes something that works for your specific situation.
